# How can I get to know a type of an object in Canvas.Children

Tags: wpf, canvas

How can I get to know a type of an object in Canvas.Children in WPF? For example I have an Ellipse and Rectangle shown on a Canvas. How to get a type of `Canvas.Children[0]`? I have something like this but it says, that "The given expression is never of the provided ('System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse') type". I need to check it:
`if (canvas.Children[0].GetType() is System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse)`

Comment: What about `Canvas.Children[0].GetType()`?

Comment: I`ve just updated the question

Comment: can you share your code what you want to achieve.. i will be easier to help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `is` here because `GetType()` returns a `Type` then you need to use `typeof` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx)):

```
if (canvas.Children[0].GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse))
```

Or you can just use directly `is` on `canvas.Children[0]`

```
if (canvas.Children[0] is System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse)
```

Comment: if (canvas.Children[0].GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse))

Comment: can you help me with this: ((Ellipse)canvas.Children[0]).SetValue(Ellipse.???, "black");  to change color

Comment: You will nedd to set the `Ellipse.Fill` `((Ellipse)canvas.Children[0]).SetValue(Ellipse.Fill, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black))` but you cannot directly set it to the string "black" you need to create a `Brush` object. By the way you can just write `((Ellipse)canvas.Children[0]).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);`

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Media.Brush' to 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'

Comment: the correct syntax is `Ellipse.FillProperty` make sure that the order of the arguments is correct: `((Ellipse)canvas.Children[0]).SetValue(Ellipse.FillProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black));`

Comment: Even simpler: `((Ellipse)canvas.Children[0]).Fill = Brushes.Black;`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if you element is ellipse or rectangle you can directly say

```
if(canvas.Children[0] is Ellipse)
```

or

```
if(canvas.Children[0] is Rectangle)
```